# Can I recover corrupted files from a hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

I have an external hard drive, on which some of the files show up to be corrupt. I have not formatted the drive by accident or anything like that. I just put my data on it, which I wanted to read back later. Some files don't even open, others open with errors, and some are fine. It seems like random pieces of data had been corrupted on my hard drive.

Is there any way to recover those damaged files? I know it's possible to recover files with special software from a hard drive that has been quick formatted, since the data itself is still present that case. But in this case, the data itself is corrupt, so I don't know if it's possible or not...

Comment: isn't possible at all, for some files as office you have a several programs to recover the logic from a file, which kind of files do you want to recover? all??

Comment: mostly ms office files and pictures

Comment: i can't post this as an answer because im not 100% sure about that, but you should try  about office files this (i know is so boring) https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Repair-a-corrupted-workbook-153a45f4-6cab-44b1-93ca-801ddcd4ea53 and about pictures im not sure if that software exist because pictures havent a defined logic.

Answer (score 1):

It is potentially possible to recover corrupted files from a hard drive if the corruption is logical instead of physical (both are possible through professional data recovery but that can be extremely costly).

Here is a free tool you can use to recover corrupted files that works pretty well in my experience https://www.piriform.com/recuva/download

Here are instructions on how to recover non deleted files from your disk https://www.piriform.com/docs/recuva/using-recuva/recovering-files-from-damaged-or-reformatted-disks

Comment: Didn't work :( Thanks though